# Excel Ribbon tab selection Chang event

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I am using VSTO Deveopment | Excel 2007 | C#. Is there any event to identify that the tab selection in excel ribbon has changed ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select VSTO Custom Ribbon in Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008359/select-vsto-custom-ribbon-in-excel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[No](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008359/select-vsto-custom-ribbon-in-excel/6847758#6847758).

Comment: This question is only in reference to VSTO with Office 2007. I am having trouble finding information on Office 2010; any ideas?

Comment: @PederRice: The Office 2010 model also doesn't expose the `change` event of ribbon tabs, but the linked answer *does* demonstrate how to speak to the Ribbon via Microsoft Active Accessibilty. I'm only passingly familiar with MSAA, so there may be a way there to access the `change` event.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm attaching another about programmatically switching tabs below, which might provide a workaround in some situations

Comment: @PederRice: That part is included in the linked answer, but again, the `ActivateTab` method isn't a workaround for identifying the, for lack of an official term, `Focused` property of a given `RibbonTab`. Changing the ribbon to become what you want is entirely unrelated to asking the ribbon *what it already is* (i.e. `get` vs. `set`). The only possibility of `get`ting ribbon information, as it stands today, is via MSAA. Moreover, the OP asked about Excel 2007, to which `ActivateTab` does not apply.

Comment: That is a good point, @PeterMajeed. I just wanted to make sure people understand that there might be workarounds, depending on their scenario, as I mentioned in my answer. You just might have to get a bit creative.

Comment: @PederRice: If only MS's Excel team were as creative (on this point!)... :)

Answer (score 2):

In VSTO2010, the ability to programmatically switch the selected tab was added. Norm Estabrook [blogged](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2010/02/23/activate-ribbon-tabs-in-office-2010-solutions-norm-estabrook.aspx) about it.

```
this.RibbonUI.ActivateTabMso("TabAddIns");
```

So while there isn't an event that can be latched onto, at least you can switch the selected tab. For instance, I'm going to use the sheet selection event; when users switch between different sheets of my workbook, I am going to change their selected tab. Each sheet will correspond to a different ribbon tab.