# Custom Tab default

Tags: excel, vsto

I have a custom tab in the ribbon in VSTO. The first time I open the excel sheet , the default tab is "Home" .I want my custom tab to be opened as a default when I open my excel sheet.Please tell me how to accomplish this.

Comment: Check the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9167092/114519 , for Office 2010.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and see this has gone unanswered. I'm using VSTO in Excel 2013. This is easily accomplished by adding code similar to this in the Load event handler of your custom ribbon class (subclass of Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonBase):

```
private void YourCustomRibbon_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
{
    RibbonUI.ActivateTab("yourCustomTabName");
}
```

"yourCustomTabName" is the ControlId of the custom RibbonTab object. It can be found in the ControlId property when you have the Ribbon Tab open in the RibbonTab designer - just under the (Name) property.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a timer to accomplish this, as the ribbon is loaded asynchronously and has no `StartupTab` property.

If you're using Excel 2007, you have to access the ribbon via the ribbon's `IAccessible` properties, which I describe in my answer to the question [Select VSTO Custom Ribbon in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008359/select-vsto-custom-ribbon-in-excel/6847758#6847758).

```cs
System.Timers.Timer tmr { get; set; }

private void Ribbon1_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
{
    tmr = new System.Timers.Timer(500)
    {
        Enabled = true
    };
    tmr.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(RibbonActivateTimer);
}

private void RibbonActivateTimer(object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    var tab = this.Tabs.SingleOrDefault(c => ((RibbonTab)c).Label == "YourStartupTab");
    if (tab != null)  // check to see if ribbon tab contains the ribbon deal
    {
        if (double.Parse(Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.Version) >= 14) //14 = xl2010
        {
            this.RibbonUI.ActivateTab(tab.ControlId.CustomId);
            DeRegisterTimer();
        }
    }
}

private void DeRegisterTimer()
{
    tmr.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For recent Office, in YourRibbon.cs file, at event Load method put these lines:

```
    private void YourRibbon_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
    {
        Globals.Ribbons.YourRibbon.RibbonUI.ActivateTab("YOUR_TAB_CONTROL_ID");
    }
```