# Switch between excel tabs within code

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, office-addins

Is there anyway to switch between excel tabs within code?

I'm creating and Add-In which will be loaded in certain conditions. Then I want my add-in tab to be selected as default tab on start-up...

Thanks

**EDIT  :**
guys, I'm talking about TABS in the ribbon. for example I want to select "Formulas" tab which is in the RIBBON at start-up. not the sheets....

Comment: Use macro recording in excel. Then you can inspirate by the generated code in VBA.

Comment: This is a duplicate. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008359/select-vsto-custom-ribbon-in-excel.

Answer (score 0):

```
((Excel.Worksheet)this.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets[1]).Select(missing);
```

Have a look at msdn:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x62t5306.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can switch between tabs if you can get a handle of the tab you need. Something like:

```
summary = (Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets["Summary Projects"];
summary.Activate();
```